# Python Как в командной строке начать считывать информацию после определённого слова?

Tags: python, файлы

На данный момент я делаю помощницу и одна из задач запись текст в txt файл(типа память).

Пример:
(Общаюсь с ней через командную строку) к примеру напишу ей: Запиши, пожалуйста, надо сделать стол.(вместо второй , могу поставить : или наоборот ничего не поставить)

Задача:
Записать в текстовый файл(может быть где угодно) только часть предложения «надо сделать стол».
Слово «Запиши» должно восприниматься как команда, а на слово «пожалуйста» не реагировать.

Вот код:

```py
    Who_you = "VBV-это Влад"
    #команда/код остановки/полная остановка системы

    import random, webbrowser
 

    lst_greetings = ["привет","приветсвую","приветик"]
    username = input("Как тебя зовут?")
    if username == Who_you:
        print("Приветики!!!")
    else:
        print(str.capitalize(lst_greetings[random.randint(0,len(lst_greetings)-1)]), username)

    stop_main = True
    while stop_main:

        process = input("").lower()


        if process == "как тебя зовут":
            print("Я госпожа Аи - помогу тебе разобраться с твоими проблемами...")


        if process == "открой ютуб":
            webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.youtube.com/')
        if process == "открой вк":
            webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://vk.com/feed')
        if process == "открой яндекс":
            webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://yandex.ru/')
        if process == "открой авито":
            webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://www.avito.ru/')
        if process == "открой переводчик":
            webbrowser.open_new_tab('https://translate.yandex.ru/')


        if "запиши" in process:
            my_file = open(r"C:\Users\berez\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\BabyFile.txt", "w+")
            my_file.write(process)
            my_file.close()


        if process == "команда/код остановки/полная остановка системы":
            stop_main = False
```

Comment: разбить [строку на слова](https://pythonim.ru/string/str-split-python) и искать требуемое "слово"

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!